# linking facebook users to users in a local database

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Users visiting my website can login with their local account, or with their facebook account. My website checks the facebook login status and receives the following information from facebook:

- `accessToken` - contains an access token for the person using the app.
- `expiresIn` - indicates the UNIX time when the token expires and needs to be renewed.
- `signedRequest` - a signed parameter that contains information about the person using the app.
- `userID` - the ID of the person using the app.

My server has a database that contains some personal information for these users, which is not provided by facebook. (Facebook has no business with it).

Right after the user logs in, the client should fetch this information from my server.

```
onFacebookLogin(response) {
  const { accessToken, expiresIn, signedRequest, userID } = response;
  const userKey = ???? ;
  infoService.getInfo(userKey).then((info) => this.info = info);
}
```

Obviously, I need a key in my database to perform this fetch:

1. This key should **identify** the user uniquely.
2. It should be **permanent**, not some temporary token, that changes every x days.
3. It should be **secure**, in the sense that it cannot just be a username. (It should be something that others cannot guess.)

Does the `accessToken`, `userID` or `signedRequest` fulfill these conditions ? Or should I use a different approach (e.g. a server side authentication) ?

*(PS: it's not in the official documentation.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For identifying returning users, you need to use the `userID`. It will be unique and it will not change for that specific App.

For mapping users across different Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/

Comment: If person A authorizes app X and app Y, will it communicate the same `userID` to both apps ? If the answer is "yes", then it's not secure at all. Since it means that the administrator of app X, could then use your `userId` to steal your personal information from app Y. It's just a matter of tampering with the client-side javascript code. (see condition 3 of my question)

Comment: the user ID is the ONLY serious way to identify returning users. i mean...it´s an "ID". anyway IDs are not shared across apps, i will add a link.

Comment: btw, no one can steal anything just with the user id. you always need tokens. and they are meant to be kept secret. also, they expire.

Comment: that sounds like an answer in itself. So, you are sure that for the same user a different `userId` gets communicated to each individual app ? - But at the same time you are saying that a `userId` isn't enough, a token is also necessary ? - And just to make my previous answer clear. I don't want to redesign facebook, I want to protect my own website against theft. I don't want others to steal from MY database. - and one more thing. there ARE other ways to do authentication (i.e. server side authentication is way more advanced, and actually verifies tokens similar to how paypal does it)

Comment: I'm just not convinced that client side authentication is safe enough. And the more I read about it, the more I get the impression that client-side authentication is only enough to extract info from facebook, but not if you have your own database that needs to be linked.

Comment: i know for a fact, and you can read this in the docs too. it´s called "app scoped id". i DID say that the userId is enough, your question was just about identifying returning users, right? a token is required to get additional data (name, email, ...).

Comment: btw, server side and client side auth are both safe enough. for example, you can just send a token from client to server, and only allow usage of tokens server side. check out various articles in the facebooks, there is at least one about securing api calls, for example.

Comment: cool ! then I guess the user id is perfectly safe. That answers my question. super ! :) thank you very much.